# Update variable in view from inside promise Angular4

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, angular5

I have the following code:

```
    <div class="row" *ngIf="!isFacebookAuth">
       <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
           <p>To start using Gili-go, simply login using facebook, give us a contact number for our drivers, and you're good to go!</p>
           <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="loginFacebook()"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Login With Facebook</button>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" *ngIf="isFacebookAuth">
      <p>test </p>
   <div>
```

Then my controller:

```
loginFacebook(){
   this.userService.signInWithFaceBook()
   .then((data) => {
      this.isFacebookAuth = true;
      console.log(data);
   })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

The login function uses firebase2, in which a promise is returned.

The value in the controller changes as it should, however for some reason the isFacebookAuth variable on the view side is  not updated and the two Div's do not change at all.

I presume this is because the variable is changed from within the promise returned by firebase.But how do I fix this?

Comment: define `this.isFacebookAuth = false;` globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trigger change detection for the updated view by calling `detectChanges()` of the [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) class.

In your component,

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

loginFacebook(){
   this.userService.signInWithFaceBook()
   .then((data) => {
      this.isFacebookAuth = true;
      console.log(data);
      this.ref.detectChanges(); // triggers another change detection cycle
   })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```